# Simplest way to register an MBean (JMX) in JBoss Fuse Fabric?

Tags: java, jmx, fuseesb, blueprint-osgi, jbossfuse

I've written a custom **MBean** for my service running in JBoss Fuse Fabric (v7.2.0.redhat-024)

- Interface: `com.mycompany.myservice.MyServiceManagerMBean`
- Implementation class: `com.mycompany.myservice.MyServiceManager`

What is the simplest way for my MBean to be registered or "discovered" by JBoss Fuse?

I tried adding the following to my blueprint.xml, but it doesnt seem to work:

```
<bean id="org.apache.cxf.management.InstrumentationManager" class="org.apache.cxf.management.jmx.InstrumentationManagerImpl">
    <property name="enabled" value="true" />
    <property name="bus" ref="cxf" />
    <property name="usePlatformMBeanServer" value="true" />
</bean>
```

I run JBoss Fuse Fabric with the profile that deploys my services, I fire up JConsole and I connect to the first Local Process named *org.apache.karaf.man.Main* (there are 2 of them).

Yet I cant find my MBean - I'm expecting to see `com.mycompany.myservice` on the MBean tab, but it isn't there.

In contrast, I can see all of my datasource jmx beans under this tree node:

`com.mycompany.anotherservice.datasources`.

However the datasource MBeans were configured by setting *jmxEnabled=true*, so I am none the wiser about how to configure and expose my own MBean.

Could someone please tell me what I need to do here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And here is a way to do this in the JBoss Fuse *blueprint.xml* configuration

```
<bean id="mbeanRegistrer" class="org.apache.karaf.management.MBeanRegistrer" init-method="init">
    <property name="bundleContext" ref="blueprintBundleContext"/>
    <property name="mbeans">
        <map>
            <entry value="com.mycompany.myservice:type=admin,name=myadminBean" key-ref="myadminBean"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thanks to my colleague Y.H. for help :)

Answer (score 0):

I received the following code snippet which should solve this problem.

First, you inject the cxf bus into a bean in blueprint.xml via `<property name="bus" ref="cxf"/>` and use it to register the bean with the InstrumentationManager:

```
    MyMBean mbean = new MyMBeanImpl();
    InstrumentationManager imanager = bus.getExtension(InstrumentationManager.class);
    final ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("org.apache.cxf:type=foo,name=bar");
    imanager.register(mbean, objectName);
```

I am still having problems with this, `bus.getExtension(InstrumentationManager.class)` returns null, but I am told this is the proper solution...

Comment: Note: this code works in plain java but wasn't working using the JBoss Fuse framework - please see my other answer for how this can work in JBoss Fuse